# Is ReliableSession.InactivityTimeout is good practice to detect errors in wcf?

Tags: c#, wcf, tcp, tcpclient

Recently i asked to implement a wcf service.
One of the problems i am facing is how to detect network failure and raise fault exception,

after some research , i found that is it possible to set receive time out property to max value,
and the inactivity to some time span,
basically it works, but my question  is am i doing good practice while i doing so?

or anybody have a better way to detect  unexpected network failure

I am using tcp binding option

```
netTcpBind.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        netTcpBind.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        netTcpBind.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        netTcpBind.ReliableSession.Enabled = true;
        netTcpBind.ReliableSession.InactivityTimeout = new TimeSpan(0,2,0);
```

Comment: @Erik Funkenbusch would you mind to take a look please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReliableSession internally sends infrastructure messages in the specified time interval & verifies whether the TCP session is still alive. This should handle all network related failure errors. Check the below link for details:
http://www.blogs.sigristsoftware.com/marcsigrist/post/Prerequisits-for-implementing-a-keep-alive-mechanism-in-WCF-30.aspx